# Why do truffle test gives two different contract address for the same smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, testing, unittesting

I was practising on a smart contract, and noticed that it gives out two different address for the same contract deployed while testing it.

```
const Test = artifacts.require('./Test.sol');

contract('Test', function(accounts) {

    describe('Test1 attributes', () => {
        let dInstance;
        beforeEach(async () => {
            dInstance = await Test.new();
        });

        it('has the address', async () => {
            const address = dInstance.address;
            const bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
            assert(address != "0x" + "0".repeat(40),'has contract address');
            console.log('Current Contract:', address);
            console.log('Current Contract balance:', bal);
        });
    });

    describe('Test2 attributes', () => {
        let dInstance;
        beforeEach(async () => {
            dInstance = await Test.new();
        });

        it('has the address', async () => {
            const address = dInstance.address;
            const bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
            assert(address != "0x" + "0".repeat(40),'has contract address');
            console.log('Current Contract:', address);
            console.log('Current Contract balance:', bal);
        });
    });


})
```

The truffle tests passed and I could see two different addresses for the same contract.

```
Contract: Test
    Test1 attributes
Current Contract: 0xCFefb2b6a91901ceb0A7Ea02a688958b0E2E1279
Current Contract balance: 0
      ✓ has the address
    Test2 attributes
Current Contract: 0xe478Aad670D90474c28b63C150bc3E404Cd0F5A3
Current Contract balance: 0
      ✓ has the address


  2 passing (273ms)
```

Could you please advice me on what might be the cause?
I would appreciate discussions over this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `beforeEach` at the beginning each `describe`, so the contract gets redeployed (a new instance of it is created) before every `it` within each `describe`.

Change it to `before`, and the contract will get deployed only once within each `describe` (you'll still get different addresses of course).

Move this `before` outside of all `describe` scopes, and the contract will get deployed only once per each execution of the test.